# vim comment issue with GNU screen and solarized

Tags: linux, vim, gnu-screen, solarized

I just installed solarized. I am using the Xresources and vim color file.
All works fine when [not inside GNU screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uhub.png).
When running vim from inside GNU screen, [the comments look different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxTmU.png) - they are not italics and have grey background; everything else looks good.
Any ideas? I have TERM set to xterm-256color, Debian GNU/Linux.
Thanks.

Comment: TERM while in screen should _always_ be "screen".

Comment: in the mean time I investigated that problem is the italics, when it's turned off, it is displayed normally (no grey background)